# phone number authentication in firebase auth in android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

How to check if the user is already authenticated in firebase Auth by phone number in Java, Android studio?
I am unable to think of any possible logic, can anyone help me with a possible outcome in code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61038436/authenticating-phone-number-without-sending-sms-in-firebase-for-android

Comment: my ques has no relevance to the above-mentioned ques link. Thank you for the help, but I want to check if the user is already authenticated or not using his phone number. like when using an email address, we can call mAuth.fetchproviderforemail(), similarly I am looking for phone number implementation.

Comment: You can use share preference for this store the id of the store in share preference when use auth like login. Its just like how you create session for current user.

Comment: If you want me to provide an example, I would be happy to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase doesn't provide any method to access authentication table from firebase console . So in your case you have to save user's info in the firebase realtime database after phone number verification . Create a node names "Users" then push the user's details into firebase realtime database . Now before sign up check the phone number if it exist in the DB then redirect user to your home page else call sign up method.

For more info check [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)